# Ползунок на телефоне не активен при 2 клике

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

День добрый.

Сайт - https://echoo.lv/family/

Имею такой ползунок, на мобильных устройствах имеется проблема такая, что можно всего 1 раз кликнуть(больше не получается выбрать число) и потом якобы "пишется текст". Не знаю как объяснить, если есть возможность, прошу посмотрите через телефон и проблема будет ясна.

Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ошибка если я не ошибаюсь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я не ошибаюсь, вот код:

```
    !function(t){function e(t,e){if(r[t]){var s=i(this);return r[t].apply(s,e)}throw new Error("method '"+t+"()' does not exist for slider.")}function i(e){var i=t(e).data("slider");if(i&&i instanceof h)return i;throw new Error(a.callingContextNotSliderInstance)}function s(e){var i=t(this),s=i.data("slider"),a="object"==typeof e&&e;return s||i.data("slider",s=new h(this,t.extend({},t.fn.arf_slider.defaults,a))),i}var a={formatInvalidInputErrorMsg:function(t){return"Invalid input value '"+t+"' passed in"},callingContextNotSliderInstance:"Calling context element does not have instance of Slider bound to it. Check your code to make sure the JQuery object returned from the call to the slider() initializer is calling the method"},h=function(e,i){var s=this.element=t(e).show(),a=s.outerWidth(),h=!0,r=this.element.parent();r.hasClass("slider")===!0?(h=!0,this.picker=r):this.picker=t('<div class="slider"><div class="arf-slider-track"><div class="slider-selection"></div><div class="arf-slider-handle"></div><div class="arf-slider-handle"></div></div><div class="arftooltip"><div class="arftooltip-arrow"></div><div class="arftooltip-inner" style="font-weight:bold"></div></div></div>').insertBefore(this.element).append(this.element),this.id=this.element.data("slider-id")||i.id,this.id&&(this.picker[0].id=this.id),"undefined"!=typeof Modernizr&&Modernizr.touch&&(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)||navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)||navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)||navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))&&(this.touchCapable=!0);var o=this.element.data("slider-tooltip")||i.tooltip;switch(this.tooltip=this.picker.find(".arftooltip"),this.tooltipInner=this.tooltip.find("div.arftooltip-inner"),this.orientation=this.element.data("slider-orientation")||i.orientation,this.orientation){case"vertical":this.picker.addClass("slider-vertical"),this.stylePos="top",this.mousePos="pageY",this.sizePos="offsetHeight",this.tooltip.addClass("right")[0].style.left="100%";break;default:this.picker.addClass("slider-horizontal").css("width",a),this.orientation="horizontal",this.stylePos="left",this.mousePos="pageX",this.sizePos="offsetWidth",this.tooltip.addClass("top")[0].style.top=-this.tooltip.outerHeight()-14+"px"}var n=["min","max","step","value"];for(key1 in n)attr=n[key1],"undefined"!=typeof s.data("slider-"+attr)?this[attr]=s.data("slider-"+attr):"undefined"!=typeof i[attr]?this[attr]=i[attr]:"undefined"!=typeof s.prop(attr)?this[attr]=s.prop(attr):this[attr]=0;this.value instanceof Array&&(this.range=!0),this.selection=this.element.data("slider-selection")||i.selection,this.selectionEl=this.picker.find(".slider-selection"),"none"===this.selection&&this.selectionEl.addClass("hide"),this.selectionElStyle=this.selectionEl[0].style,this.handle1=this.picker.find(".arf-slider-handle:first"),this.handle1Stype=this.handle1[0].style,this.handle2=this.picker.find(".arf-slider-handle:last"),this.handle2Stype=this.handle2[0].style;var l=this.element.data("arf-slider-handle")||i.handle;switch(l){case"round":this.handle1.addClass("round"),this.handle2.addClass("round");break;case"triangle":this.handle1.addClass("triangle"),this.handle2.addClass("triangle")}if(this.range?(this.value[0]=Math.max(this.min,Math.min(this.max,this.value[0])),this.value[1]=Math.max(this.min,Math.min(this.max,this.value[1]))):(this.value=[Math.max(this.min,Math.min(this.max,this.value))],this.handle2.addClass("hide"),"after"===this.selection?this.value[1]=this.max:this.value[1]=this.min),this.diff=this.max-this.min,this.percentage=[100*(this.value[0]-this.min)/this.diff,100*(this.value[1]-this.min)/this.diff,100*this.step/this.diff],this.offset=this.picker.offset(),this.size=this.picker[0][this.sizePos],this.formater=i.formater,this.reversed=this.element.data("slider-reversed")||i.reversed,this.layout(),this.touchCapable?this.picker.on({touchstart:t.proxy(this.mousedown,this)}):this.picker.on({mousedown:t.proxy(this.mousedown,this)}),"hide"===o?this.tooltip.addClass("hide"):"always"===o?(this.showTooltip(),this.alwaysShowTooltip=!0):this.picker.on({mouseenter:t.proxy(this.showTooltip,this),mouseleave:t.proxy(this.hideTooltip,this)}),1==h){var d=this.getValue(),u=this.calculateValue();this.element.trigger({type:"slide",value:u}).data("value",u).prop("value",u),d!==u&&this.element.trigger({type:"slideChange","new":u,old:d}).data("value",u).prop("value",u)}this.enabled=i.enabled&&(void 0===this.element.data("slider-enabled")||this.element.data("slider-enabled")===!0),this.enabled||this.disable()};h.prototype={constructor:h,over:!1,inDrag:!1,showTooltip:function(){this.tooltip.addClass("in"),this.over=!0},hideTooltip:function(){this.inDrag===!1&&this.alwaysShowTooltip!==!0&&this.tooltip.removeClass("in"),this.over=!1},layout:function(){var t;t=this.reversed?[100-this.percentage[0],this.percentage[1]]:[this.percentage[0],this.percentage[1]],t[0]=t[0]?t[0]:0,t[1]=t[1]?t[1]:0,this.handle1Stype[this.stylePos]=t[0]+"%",this.handle2Stype[this.stylePos]=t[1]+"%","vertical"===this.orientation?(this.selectionElStyle.top=Math.min(t[0],t[1])+"%",this.selectionElStyle.height=Math.abs(t[0]-t[1])+"%"):(this.selectionElStyle.left=Math.min(t[0],t[1])+"%",this.selectionElStyle.width=Math.abs(t[0]-t[1])+"%"),this.range?(this.tooltipInner.text(this.formater(this.value[0])+" : "+this.formater(this.value[1])),this.tooltip[0].style[this.stylePos]=this.size*(t[0]+(t[1]-t[0])/2)/100-("vertical"===this.orientation?this.tooltip.outerHeight()/2:this.tooltip.outerWidth()/2)+"px"):(this.tooltipInner.text(this.formater(this.value[0])),this.tooltip[0].style[this.stylePos]=this.size*t[0]/100-("vertical"===this.orientation?this.tooltip.outerHeight()/2:this.tooltip.outerWidth()/2)+"px")},mousedown:function(e){if(!this.isEnabled())return!1;this.touchCapable&&"touchstart"===e.type&&(e=e.originalEvent),this.offset=this.picker.offset(),this.size=this.picker[0][this.sizePos];var i=this.getPercentage(e);if(this.range){var s=Math.abs(this.percentage[0]-i),a=Math.abs(this.percentage[1]-i);this.dragged=a>s?0:1}else this.dragged=0;this.percentage[this.dragged]=this.reversed?100-i:i,this.layout(),navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)||navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)||navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)||navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)?this.touchCapable=!0:this.touchCapable=!1,this.touchCapable?t(document).on({touchmove:t.proxy(this.mousemove,this),touchend:t.proxy(this.mouseup,this)}):t(document).on({mousemove:t.proxy(this.mousemove,this),mouseup:t.proxy(this.mouseup,this)}),this.inDrag=!0;var h=this.calculateValue();return this.setValue(h),this.element.trigger({type:"slideStart",value:h}).trigger({type:"slide",value:h}),!1},mousemove:function(t){if(!this.isEnabled())return!1;this.touchCapable&&"touchmove"===t.type&&(t=t.originalEvent);var e=this.getPercentage(t);this.range&&(0===this.dragged&&this.percentage[1]<e?(this.percentage[0]=this.percentage[1],this.dragged=1):1===this.dragged&&this.percentage[0]>e&&(this.percentage[1]=this.percentage[0],this.dragged=0)),this.percentage[this.dragged]=this.reversed?100-e:e,this.layout();var i=this.calculateValue();return this.setValue(i),this.element.trigger({type:"slide",value:i}).data("value",i).prop("value",i),!1},mouseup:function(){if(!this.isEnabled())return!1;this.touchCapable?t(document).off({touchmove:this.mousemove,touchend:this.mouseup}):t(document).off({mousemove:this.mousemove,mouseup:this.mouseup}),this.inDrag=!1,this.over===!1&&this.hideTooltip();var e=this.calculateValue();return this.layout(),this.element.data("value",e).prop("value",e).trigger({type:"slideStop",value:e}),!1},calculateValue:function(){var t;return this.range?(t=[Math.max(this.min,this.min+Math.round(this.diff*this.percentage[0]/100/this.step)*this.step),Math.min(this.max,this.min+Math.round(this.diff*this.percentage[1]/100/this.step)*this.step)],this.value=t):(t=this.min+Math.round(this.diff*this.percentage[0]/100/this.step)*this.step,t<this.min?t=this.min:t>this.max&&(t=this.max),t=parseFloat(t.toFixed(2)),this.value=[t,this.value[1]]),t},getPercentage:function(t){this.touchCapable&&(t=t.touches[0]);var e=100*(t[this.mousePos]-this.offset[this.stylePos])/this.size;return e=Math.round(e/this.percentage[2])*this.percentage[2],Math.max(0,Math.min(100,e))},getValue:function(){return this.range?this.value:this.value[0]},setValue:function(t){this.value=this.validateInputValue(t),this.range?(this.value[0]=Math.max(this.min,Math.min(this.max,this.value[0])),this.value[1]=Math.max(this.min,Math.min(this.max,this.value[1]))):(this.value=[Math.max(this.min,Math.min(this.max,this.value.toFixed(2)))],this.handle2.addClass("hide"),"after"===this.selection?this.value[1]=this.max:this.value[1]=this.min),this.diff=this.max-this.min,this.percentage=[100*(this.value[0]-this.min)/this.diff,100*(this.value[1]-this.min)/this.diff,100*this.step/this.diff],this.layout()},validateInputValue:function(t){if("number"==typeof t)return t;if(t instanceof Array)return t.forEach(function(t){if("number"!=typeof t)throw new Error(a.formatInvalidInputErrorMsg(t))}),t;throw new Error(a.formatInvalidInputErrorMsg(t))},destroy:function(){this.element.show().insertBefore(this.picker),this.picker.remove(),t(this.element).removeData("slider"),t(this.element).off()},disable:function(){this.enabled=!1,this.picker.addClass("slider-disabled"),this.element.trigger("slideDisabled")},enable:function(){this.enabled=!0,this.picker.removeClass("slider-disabled"),this.element.trigger("slideEnabled")},toggle:function(){this.enabled?this.disable():this.enable()},isEnabled:function(){return this.enabled}};var r={getValue:h.prototype.getValue,setValue:h.prototype.setValue,destroy:h.prototype.destroy,disable:h.prototype.disable,enable:h.prototype.enable,toggle:h.prototype.toggle,isEnabled:h.prototype.isEnabled};t.fn.arf_slider=function(t){if("string"==typeof t){var i=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);return e.call(this,t,i)}return s.call(this,t)},t.fn.arf_slider.defaults={min:0,max:10,step:1,orientation:"horizontal",value:5,selection:"before",tooltip:"show",handle:"round",reversed:!1,enabled:!0,formater:function(t){return t}},t.fn.arf_slider.Constructor=h}(window.jQuery);
```

А вот uncompressed:

```
     ! function(t) {
function e(t, e) {
    if (r[t]) {
        var s = i(this);
        return r[t].apply(s, e)
    }
    throw new Error("method '" + t + "()' does not exist for slider.")
}

function i(e) {
    var i = t(e).data("slider");
    if (i && i instanceof h) return i;
    throw new Error(a.callingContextNotSliderInstance)
}

function s(e) {
    var i = t(this),
        s = i.data("slider"),
        a = "object" == typeof e && e;
    return s || i.data("slider", s = new h(this, t.extend({}, t.fn.arf_slider.defaults, a))), i
}
var a = {
        formatInvalidInputErrorMsg: function(t) {
            return "Invalid input value '" + t + "' passed in"
        },
        callingContextNotSliderInstance: "Calling context element does not have instance of Slider bound to it. Check your code to make sure the JQuery object returned from the call to the slider() initializer is calling the method"
    },
    h = function(e, i) {
        var s = this.element = t(e).show(),
            a = s.outerWidth(),
            h = !0,
            r = this.element.parent();
        r.hasClass("slider") === !0 ? (h = !0, this.picker = r) : this.picker = t('<div class="slider"><div class="arf-slider-track"><div class="slider-selection"></div><div class="arf-slider-handle"></div><div class="arf-slider-handle"></div></div><div class="arftooltip"><div class="arftooltip-arrow"></div><div class="arftooltip-inner" style="font-weight:bold"></div></div></div>').insertBefore(this.element).append(this.element), this.id = this.element.data("slider-id") || i.id, this.id && (this.picker[0].id = this.id), "undefined" != typeof Modernizr && Modernizr.touch && (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) && (this.touchCapable = !0);
        var o = this.element.data("slider-tooltip") || i.tooltip;
        switch (this.tooltip = this.picker.find(".arftooltip"), this.tooltipInner = this.tooltip.find("div.arftooltip-inner"), this.orientation = this.element.data("slider-orientation") || i.orientation, this.orientation) {
            case "vertical":
                this.picker.addClass("slider-vertical"), this.stylePos = "top", this.mousePos = "pageY", this.sizePos = "offsetHeight", this.tooltip.addClass("right")[0].style.left = "100%";
                break;
            default:
                this.picker.addClass("slider-horizontal").css("width", a), this.orientation = "horizontal", this.stylePos = "left", this.mousePos = "pageX", this.sizePos = "offsetWidth", this.tooltip.addClass("top")[0].style.top = -this.tooltip.outerHeight() - 14 + "px"
        }
        var n = ["min", "max", "step", "value"];
        for (key1 in n) attr = n[key1], "undefined" != typeof s.data("slider-" + attr) ? this[attr] = s.data("slider-" + attr) : "undefined" != typeof i[attr] ? this[attr] = i[attr] : "undefined" != typeof s.prop(attr) ? this[attr] = s.prop(attr) : this[attr] = 0;
        this.value instanceof Array && (this.range = !0), this.selection = this.element.data("slider-selection") || i.selection, this.selectionEl = this.picker.find(".slider-selection"), "none" === this.selection && this.selectionEl.addClass("hide"), this.selectionElStyle = this.selectionEl[0].style, this.handle1 = this.picker.find(".arf-slider-handle:first"), this.handle1Stype = this.handle1[0].style, this.handle2 = this.picker.find(".arf-slider-handle:last"), this.handle2Stype = this.handle2[0].style;
        var l = this.element.data("arf-slider-handle") || i.handle;
        switch (l) {
            case "round":
                this.handle1.addClass("round"), this.handle2.addClass("round");
                break;
            case "triangle":
                this.handle1.addClass("triangle"), this.handle2.addClass("triangle")
        }
        if (this.range ? (this.value[0] = Math.max(this.min, Math.min(this.max, this.value[0])), this.value[1] = Math.max(this.min, Math.min(this.max, this.value[1]))) : (this.value = [Math.max(this.min, Math.min(this.max, this.value))], this.handle2.addClass("hide"), "after" === this.selection ? this.value[1] = this.max : this.value[1] = this.min), this.diff = this.max - this.min, this.percentage = [100 * (this.value[0] - this.min) / this.diff, 100 * (this.value[1] - this.min) / this.diff, 100 * this.step / this.diff], this.offset = this.picker.offset(), this.size = this.picker[0][this.sizePos], this.formater = i.formater, this.reversed = this.element.data("slider-reversed") || i.reversed, this.layout(), this.touchCapable ? this.picker.on({
                touchstart: t.proxy(this.mousedown, this)
            }) : this.picker.on({
                mousedown: t.proxy(this.mousedown, this)
            }), "hide" === o ? this.tooltip.addClass("hide") : "always" === o ? (this.showTooltip(), this.alwaysShowTooltip = !0) : this.picker.on({
                mouseenter: t.proxy(this.showTooltip, this),
                mouseleave: t.proxy(this.hideTooltip, this)
            }), 1 == h) {
            var d = this.getValue(),
                u = this.calculateValue();
            this.element.trigger({
                type: "slide",
                value: u
            }).data("value", u).prop("value", u), d !== u && this.element.trigger({
                type: "slideChange",
                "new": u,
                old: d
            }).data("value", u).prop("value", u)
        }
        this.enabled = i.enabled && (void 0 === this.element.data("slider-enabled") || this.element.data("slider-enabled") === !0), this.enabled || this.disable()
    };
h.prototype = {
    constructor: h,
    over: !1,
    inDrag: !1,
    showTooltip: function() {
        this.tooltip.addClass("in"), this.over = !0
    },
    hideTooltip: function() {
        this.inDrag === !1 && this.alwaysShowTooltip !== !0 && this.tooltip.removeClass("in"), this.over = !1
    },
    layout: function() {
        var t;
        t = this.reversed ? [100 - this.percentage[0], this.percentage[1]] : [this.percentage[0], this.percentage[1]], t[0] = t[0] ? t[0] : 0, t[1] = t[1] ? t[1] : 0, this.handle1Stype[this.stylePos] = t[0] + "%", this.handle2Stype[this.stylePos] = t[1] + "%", "vertical" === this.orientation ? (this.selectionElStyle.top = Math.min(t[0], t[1]) + "%", this.selectionElStyle.height = Math.abs(t[0] - t[1]) + "%") : (this.selectionElStyle.left = Math.min(t[0], t[1]) + "%", this.selectionElStyle.width = Math.abs(t[0] - t[1]) + "%"), this.range ? (this.tooltipInner.text(this.formater(this.value[0]) + " : " + this.formater(this.value[1])), this.tooltip[0].style[this.stylePos] = this.size * (t[0] + (t[1] - t[0]) / 2) / 100 - ("vertical" === this.orientation ? this.tooltip.outerHeight() / 2 : this.tooltip.outerWidth() / 2) + "px") : (this.tooltipInner.text(this.formater(this.value[0])), this.tooltip[0].style[this.stylePos] = this.size * t[0] / 100 - ("vertical" === this.orientation ? this.tooltip.outerHeight() / 2 : this.tooltip.outerWidth() / 2) + "px")
    },
    mousedown: function(e) {
        if (!this.isEnabled()) return !1;
        this.touchCapable && "touchstart" === e.type && (e = e.originalEvent), this.offset = this.picker.offset(), this.size = this.picker[0][this.sizePos];
        var i = this.getPercentage(e);
        if (this.range) {
            var s = Math.abs(this.percentage[0] - i),
                a = Math.abs(this.percentage[1] - i);
            this.dragged = a > s ? 0 : 1
        } else this.dragged = 0;
        this.percentage[this.dragged] = this.reversed ? 100 - i : i, this.layout(), navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ? this.touchCapable = !0 : this.touchCapable = !1, this.touchCapable ? t(document).on({
            touchmove: t.proxy(this.mousemove, this),
            touchend: t.proxy(this.mouseup, this)
        }) : t(document).on({
            mousemove: t.proxy(this.mousemove, this),
            mouseup: t.proxy(this.mouseup, this)
        }), this.inDrag = !0;
        var h = this.calculateValue();
        return this.setValue(h), this.element.trigger({
            type: "slideStart",
            value: h
        }).trigger({
            type: "slide",
            value: h
        }), !1
    },
    mousemove: function(t) {
        if (!this.isEnabled()) return !1;
        this.touchCapable && "touchmove" === t.type && (t = t.originalEvent);
        var e = this.getPercentage(t);
        this.range && (0 === this.dragged && this.percentage[1] < e ? (this.percentage[0] = this.percentage[1], this.dragged = 1) : 1 === this.dragged && this.percentage[0] > e && (this.percentage[1] = this.percentage[0], this.dragged = 0)), this.percentage[this.dragged] = this.reversed ? 100 - e : e, this.layout();
        var i = this.calculateValue();
        return this.setValue(i), this.element.trigger({
            type: "slide",
            value: i
        }).data("value", i).prop("value", i), !1
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        if (!this.isEnabled()) return !1;
        this.touchCapable ? t(document).off({
            touchmove: this.mousemove,
            touchend: this.mouseup
        }) : t(document).off({
            mousemove: this.mousemove,
            mouseup: this.mouseup
        }), this.inDrag = !1, this.over === !1 && this.hideTooltip();
        var e = this.calculateValue();
        return this.layout(), this.element.data("value", e).prop("value", e).trigger({
            type: "slideStop",
            value: e
        }), !1
    },
    calculateValue: function() {
        var t;
        return this.range ? (t = [Math.max(this.min, this.min + Math.round(this.diff * this.percentage[0] / 100 / this.step) * this.step), Math.min(this.max, this.min + Math.round(this.diff * this.percentage[1] / 100 / this.step) * this.step)], this.value = t) : (t = this.min + Math.round(this.diff * this.percentage[0] / 100 / this.step) * this.step, t < this.min ? t = this.min : t > this.max && (t = this.max), t = parseFloat(t.toFixed(2)), this.value = [t, this.value[1]]), t
    },
    getPercentage: function(t) {
        this.touchCapable && (t = t.touches[0]);
        var e = 100 * (t[this.mousePos] - this.offset[this.stylePos]) / this.size;
        return e = Math.round(e / this.percentage[2]) * this.percentage[2], Math.max(0, Math.min(100, e))
    },
    getValue: function() {
        return this.range ? this.value : this.value[0]
    },
    setValue: function(t) {
        this.value = this.validateInputValue(t), this.range ? (this.value[0] = Math.max(this.min, Math.min(this.max, this.value[0])), this.value[1] = Math.max(this.min, Math.min(this.max, this.value[1]))) : (this.value = [Math.max(this.min, Math.min(this.max, this.value.toFixed(2)))], this.handle2.addClass("hide"), "after" === this.selection ? this.value[1] = this.max : this.value[1] = this.min), this.diff = this.max - this.min, this.percentage = [100 * (this.value[0] - this.min) / this.diff, 100 * (this.value[1] - this.min) / this.diff, 100 * this.step / this.diff], this.layout()
    },
    validateInputValue: function(t) {
        if ("number" == typeof t) return t;
        if (t instanceof Array) return t.forEach(function(t) {
            if ("number" != typeof t) throw new Error(a.formatInvalidInputErrorMsg(t))
        }), t;
        throw new Error(a.formatInvalidInputErrorMsg(t))
    },
    destroy: function() {
        this.element.show().insertBefore(this.picker), this.picker.remove(), t(this.element).removeData("slider"), t(this.element).off()
    },
    disable: function() {
        this.enabled = !1, this.picker.addClass("slider-disabled"), this.element.trigger("slideDisabled")
    },
    enable: function() {
        this.enabled = !0, this.picker.removeClass("slider-disabled"), this.element.trigger("slideEnabled")
    },
    toggle: function() {
        this.enabled ? this.disable() : this.enable()
    },
    isEnabled: function() {
        return this.enabled
    }
};
var r = {
    getValue: h.prototype.getValue,
    setValue: h.prototype.setValue,
    destroy: h.prototype.destroy,
    disable: h.prototype.disable,
    enable: h.prototype.enable,
    toggle: h.prototype.toggle,
    isEnabled: h.prototype.isEnabled
};
t.fn.arf_slider = function(t) {
    if ("string" == typeof t) {
        var i = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return e.call(this, t, i)
    }
    return s.call(this, t)
}, t.fn.arf_slider.defaults = {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    step: 1,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    value: 5,
    selection: "before",
    tooltip: "show",
    handle: "round",
    reversed: !1,
    enabled: !0,
    formater: function(t) {
        return t
    }
}, t.fn.arf_slider.Constructor = h
```

}(window.jQuery);

Comment: там не в js дело - input налезает на ползунок, поэтому когда пользователь кликает на ползунок, активируется поле input для ввода.

Comment: @mix Спасибо. А как это поправить? Можете подсказать?

Comment: я не знаком с данным плагином, но, полагаю, что input не используется визуально, поэтому можно попробовать выставить ему `display:none` или же стилями сдвинуть его в свободное пространство, чтобы он не мешался.

Comment: @mix Смотрите, я сейчас убрал input, да, теперь нету поля, но всё равно ползунок не передвинуть 2 раз, только 1. Что думаете?

Comment: @mix Вы были частично правы. В js ошибка тоже. Вот в этой строчке - this.touchCapable && (t = t.touches[0]);. Сейчас я её убрал и всё хорошо.